# error "The variable var is not defined." number -2753 from "var" in a method

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write a method that waits for an element on a webpage to appear before continuing, this code works when not placed in a method but I cannot appear to place it in one without getting the error above

```
on waitForId(idText)
set var to false
set idText to "\"" & idText & "\""
repeat until var is true
    tell application "Safari"
        set var to (do JavaScript "document.contains(document.getElementById(idText));") in current tab of first window
    end tell
    delay 0.2
end repeat
return true
end waitForId


tell application "Safari"
global var
set var to false
if not (exists document 1) then reopen
tell current tab of window 1 to set URL to "https://www.google.com/?client=safari#channel=mac_bm"
tell current tab to activate
log "starting wait"
my waitForId("hplogo")

log "done waiting"
end tell
```

The "hplogo" is a google sign for testing. When run:

```
error "The variable var is not defined." number -2753 from "var"
```

Comment: yeah global goes across multiple runs so don't want that, the var was undefined because of the ending ) was making set var to (javascript stuff) + in current tab rather than including that in the JS command

Answer (score 1):

figured it out, a misplaced ) and concatenating the javascript to make it a variable, silly question.

```
on waitForId(idText)
set wait to false
set idText to "\"" & idText & "\""
repeat until wait is true
    tell application "Safari"
        set wait to (do JavaScript "document.contains(document.getElementById(" & idText & "));" in current tab of first window)
    end tell
    delay 0.2
end repeat
return true
end waitForId


tell application "Safari"
set var to false
if not (exists document 1) then reopen
tell current tab of window 1 to set URL to "https://www.google.com/?client=safari#channel=mac_bm"
tell current tab to activate
log "starting wait"
my waitForId("hplogo")

log "done waiting"
end tell
```